# How to create a pandas Series with a dtype which is a subclass of float?

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

I would like to create a pandas Series of a type derived from float. However, pandas automatically recast it as float:

```py
import pandas as pd

class PValue(float):
    def __str__(self):
        if self < 1e-4:
            return '<1e-4'
        return super().__str__()


s = pd.Series([0.1, 0.12e-5])
s = s.map(PValue)

print(s.apply(type)) # -> returns `float`, but I want to get `PValue`
```

Comment: Can you update your question with something more specific. That MyFloat class appears peculiarly useless, so it's hard to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, beware the [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd need to use an [extension type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#extension-types) to get it to work how you want.

But, a class with only one method probably shouldn't be a class. Check out [Stop Writing Classes by Jack Diederich from PyCon 2012](https://youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0). You can do the same thing with a formatter function:

```
def pvalue(x: float) -> str:
    if x < 1e-4:
        return '<1e-4'
    return str(x)
```

Then for example:

```
s = pd.Series([0.1, 0.12e-5])
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', pvalue):
    s
```

```
0     0.1
1   <1e-4
dtype: float64
```

Or, for use in a dataframe, if you don't want to format all the columns as `pvalue`s, [use a style](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Formatting-Values):

```
pd.DataFrame({'p': s}).style.format({'p': pvalue})
```

This is shown in Jupyter as an HTML table like this:

```
        p
0     0.1
1   <1e-4
```